# SQL Server 2005 Unicode string sorting problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, sorting

I have a table named 'Soum'. this table has `NVARCHAR(100)` field named `'Name'`. But sort by `name`, that wrong working. Please see picture. After executing query.

[image]

First red row is wrong sorted.

I don't understand that why this is wrong working. I was checked character is same or not. But 'Ө' character is same in red rows. I'm trying to reinsert this 3 rows. But result is same.

How can I fix this error? I don't want to add Order field. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you got the collation of the column set right? Collations are rules for comparing characters, because the same characters might have different alphabetical order in different languages. Although I think that this case should sort correctly no matter what the collation, it would still be the first thing I check, because you can never tell with Unicode...

Comment: My Database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: How to create custom collation. My language is Mongolia. But Mongolian collation is not found.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 seems to support more collations, e.g. a [Mongolian (PRC) - Cyrillic_General_100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx) which is a new feature in SQL Server 2008 - not supported in 2005, sorry.

Comment: This looks like Mongolian written with Cyrillic characters. Is there a general collation for Cyrillic?

Comment: I'm using ADO.NET Entity Framework. Can fix this problem using LINQ in c#?

Comment: @ebattulga: that's a method of storing and retrieving data. The collation is a property of the table, i.e. independent of the method used to access the table.

Comment: Apparently 'Ө' symbol is just ignored in current collation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check sorting for "л" and "г"? Аdd 2 records for test with that names and sort them by name. I think problem in "г"

Answer (score 0):

You can run this for get all collation:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') as CodePage,
    COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'LCID') as LCID,
    COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'ComparisonStyle') as ComparisonStyle,
    description
FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
```

and this for your problem

```
select * from soum order by [name] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
-- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = your collation
```