# Sort UniCode Character in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i am building an website which is in Russian language.

As all knows Russian language contains unicode characters.So while sorting its not showing sorted manner.

I have written sort in sql server query.

My question is how to sort unicode characters in sql server or in asp.net.

Please help

we can see its not sorted

free image hosting.net/ newuploads/ odh8j.png

Thanks

Comment: where u want sorted resut? at asp.net page or at sql server side?

Comment: **I have written sort in sql server query.** So whats the problem you have unicode while binding execute it in a same manner when you are doing sorting

Comment: both, i am fetching sorted data form sql server and showing in a dropdown

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: My column datatype is nvarchar.but still its not sorting

Comment: I have attached an image please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510048/sql-server-2005-unicode-string-sorting-problem

Answer (score 0):

to sort in-memory objects `using System.Linq;`

sample object

```
public class MyAccount
{
  public int ID {set; get;}
  public string Name {set; get;}
  public DateTime Created {set; get;}
}
```

sorting method

```
IEnumerable<MyAccount> accounts;
//map your DB query result to object list
//accounts = new List<MyAccount>();
//accounts.Add(/*...*/); 

var result = accounts.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList(); //or OrderByDescending()
```

Comment: i m using stored procedure. can't change it to Linq.